# how to remove ubuntu 12.04 from dual booting with windows xp with xp installation cd

Tags: dual-boot, uninstall

I have dual booting system with Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows XP. Now I want to remove Ubuntu 12.04 and retained Windows XP.

How do I remove the Ubuntu 12.04 with Windows XP installation CD command prompt?

Comment: Look at the questions that show up under the "related" category here.

Answer (score -1):

If you used the Wubi installer and installed Ubuntu from while booted in windows, you can simply uninstall Ubuntu in the same manner as you would uninstall an application from windows.
If you installed Ubuntu from a live CD on a separate partition, all you must do is delete the partition that contains Ubuntu.

[This link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#Uninstallation) might be useful :)

Comment: "all you must do is delete the partition that contains Ubuntu". This will leave GRUB installed and at next boot OP will get GRUB rescue prompt. See the downvoted answer in the suggested duplicate.